# Запуск 2-ух экземпляров Unity на одном проекте

Tags: windows, unity3d

В общем, у меня есть мультиплеерный проект и мне иногда нужно проводить тесты играя сам с собой => мне нужно запускать 2 экземпляра редактора, а Unity это не позволяет сделать.

Какие могут быть решения данной проблемы?

Самое простое- это держать 2 копии проекта, но если происходит переключение ветки в git, то нужно все снова копировать, а это долго + Unity будет делать реинпорт.

Comment: Запустить от ещё одного виндоюзера поможет?